# Does ultralimit of sequence change after shift?

Tags: general-topology, limits, logic, filters

Let

- $(a_n)$ be a bounded sequence of numbers,
- $\omega$ be an non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$,

then one can assign a limit along ultrafilter $(\omega-)\lim a_n$ to it as is said [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit#Limit_of_a_sequence_of_points_with_respect_to_an_ultrafilter). This limit remains the same, if one changes a finite number of the elements of sequence.

But will it be shift-invariant, i.e. equal for sequences $(a_n)$ and $(a_{n+1})$? If not, can one choose an ultrafilter with this property at least for sequences with $a_{n+1}-a_n \to 0$?

Comment: consider the sequence $(1,0,1,0,1,0,\dots)$; its limit (0 or 1) will change under the shift for any ultrafilter (the limit depends on whether the set of even numbers or rather the set of odd numbers is in the ultrafilter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question at the end of your post, any ultrafilter $U$ will be shift invariant (at least by one place) on sequences $(a_n)$ with the property $\lim_U (a_{n+1}-a_n) = 0$.

Indeed, $\lim_U (a_{n+1}) = \lim_U(a_n + (a_{n+1} - a_n)) = \lim_U(a_n) + \lim_U(a_{n+1}-a_n) = \lim_U(a_n)$, just using linearity of $\lim_U$.

Above I've taken your suggested condition $a_{n+1}-a_n\to 0$ to mean convergence with respect to $U$. Of course, if the sequence of differences actually converges, this will agree with convergence according to $U$ as long as $U$ is nonprincipal. There's one subtlety with using $\lim_U$ here, though. The limit assigned to the sequence $(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ by $U$ might not be shift invariant! So if you want to shift $k$ places to the right, you need that $\lim_U(a_{n+k}-a_n) = 0$. This issue goes away if you use the stronger assumption that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n) = 0$, since this notion of limit *is* shift-invariant.

Answer (score 2):

No free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$ has this property. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$. Let $E=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, and define a sequence

$$a:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R:n\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }n\in E\\
1,&\text{if }n\notin E\;.
\end{cases}$$

If $E\in\mathscr{U}$, then $\mathscr{U}$-$\lim a=0$, and if not, then $\mathscr{U}$-$\lim a=1$. Now let $b:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R:n\mapsto a_{n+1}$; clearly $\mathscr{U}$-$\lim b=1-\mathscr{U}$-$\lim a$.

**Added:** This is of course only an answer to the first question. Alex Kruckman has dealt nicely with the second question.

Comment: This is a nice example and answers the main part of the question. I'm confused as to why it was downvoted...

Comment: @Alex: I've been getting one or two a day for the last week or two, all on correct answers or good hints. *shrug*